expo router navigate between tabs
I am using "expo-router": "^3.4.10". My sitemap looks like this:
  (tabs)/
    home/index
    chat/index
      [chatId]/index
    jobs/index
      [jobId]/index
        offers/index
        users/index

When I navigate from (tabs)/jobs/:id/offers to (tabs)/chat/:id the page of one chat appears, that is, in the chat tab, the stack of screens is cleared and screen of one chat are added to it. When I try to go back, it redirects me to the home/index path, then I select tab chat again and there is the same screen (screen of one chat), it is not possible to delete it from there, but I want to see the page of all chats (tabs)/chat/index.
I need that when I return from (tabs)/chat/:id I end up in (tabs)/chat .
For navigation I use router.replace(), router.push() and router.navigate(), the result is always the same/

did you figure this out?
